# Condition in IF-Condition in UiPath

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot

Due to the fact, that i´m completly new to UiPath, I need some minor help implementing an if condition.

My Problem:

- Im using the Bot to search for several Post sendings in the Browser on the DHL-Homepage. The Bot works fine, but due to changes on the Homepage, minor changes have to be done.
- The tasks are: Open Browser, clicking a field, type something in the field, click the button for search. In some cases, after clicking the search button, the system wants to know the shipping date. Now I need to implement an if-condition. If the field for Shipping date appears, then type the date and click the search button again. Else go ahead with the next step. The If and Else sequences are implemented already, but i cant figure out how to implement the necessary condition [VB-Ausdruck eingeben].

You can see the If-Else Condition below.

Hope the problem is clear and someone can help me.

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: When will that if statement be triggered? Could you improve your question? I'm not sure what you try to do.

Comment: The if statement will be triggered, when a special field inside the Browserwindow appears. I had the problem, that i wasn´t sure how to deal with the 'Condition'-Field inside the If-statement.

But now I figured it out. The Answer is below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution.

I´ve added an 'Element Exists' before the If-Activity. Declared an Variabletype 'boolean', and wrote in the If Condition 'booleanOutput=True' -> If the field, which is indetified by the Element Exists- activity, the Then part will start, otherwise the empty Else part starts.

[image]